# Writing to shared memory

Tags: c++, file, winapi, shared-memory

How can I write from a file to shared memory using the Win32 API?

I have this code:

```
hFile = CreateFile("input.map",
  GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
  FILE_SHARE_READ,
  NULL,
  OPEN_ALWAYS,
  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
  NULL);

  hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(hFile,
  NULL,
  PAGE_READWRITE,
  0,
  0,
  TEXT("SharedObject"));

  lpMapAddress = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,
  FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
  0,
  0,
  0);

  ReadFile(
  hFile,
  lpMapAddress,
  75,
  &bytesRead,
  NULL);

  sprintf((char*)lpMapAddress, "<output 1>");

  printf((char*) lpMapAddress);
```

However, the printf call only returns "< output 1 >" and not the contents of the file.

EDIT:
Found the problem. I'm writing to the input file when I call sprintf. But I still don't know why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the entire code sample? It looks to me like the call to `sprintf` places a null-terminated string at `lpMapAddress`, which effectively overwrites whatever you read from the file--at least for the purposes of your `printf` statement.

If you want to replace the first part of what you read with the string `"<output 1>"`, you could do this after reading the file:

```
char *tmp = "<output 1>";
strncpy((char*)lpMapAddress, tmp, strlen(tmp));
```

That copies the text of the string but not its null terminator.

Comment: This helped! Used strcat() in the end.

Answer (score 2):

The `sprintf` stores a NUL after `<output 1>`, and `printf` stops at the first NUL.

(Also, it's a bad idea to pass some random file as the format to `printf`.  What if it contained `%` characters?  But that's another issue.)

> I'm writing to the input file when I
>   call sprintf. But I still don't know
>   why...

Because that's what `MapViewOfFile` *does*.  It associates the file's contents with a block of memory.  The current contents of the file appear in the memory block, and any changes you make to that memory are written to the file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to call ReadFile after mapping. Just access the content from the lpMapAddress.

However, using constants for MapViewOfFile makes no benefit from using memory file mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are getting at here. It doesn't matter what code you put before; That last line is *always* going to return the string you placed into the buffer in the previous "sprintf" line. Since that is "`<output 1>`", yes that's what will be returned.